# PHP: Returning Both a 2D Array and Individual Variables Together

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I would need to **return a 2D array with several individual variables** from a PHP script to JavaScript client. The script is called via AJAX call.

I have been experimenting with this a lot, but I simply can not find a solution. The code below shows how to return a plain 2D array. That works fine. But how to add, please, say three individual variables (say $var1, $var2, $var3) to the $outputArray and return them together?

I would like to use `json_encode()` to return the information from the server to the client.

```
// prepare output array
$outputArray = array();

// construct 2D array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    // add row to array
    $outputArray[] = $row;
}

// close database connection
mysqli_close($dbc);

// construct and output JSON
echo json_encode($outputArray);
```

I use:
 - PHP v5.5.8
 - MySQL v5.6.15
 - JavaScrip on the client side
 - HTML 5

I hope the information provided is sufficient to illustrate what I am looking for. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
$outputArray[] = $var1;
$outputArray[] = $var2;
$outputArray[] = $var3;
```

Or with specific index

```
$outputArray["Additional1"] = $var1;
$outputArray["Additional2"] = $var2;
$outputArray["Additional3"] = $var3;
```

I don't know exactly what are criteria of adding, but I hope it is enough for you to figure out rest of it.

It's legal in both PHP and JavaScript to have mixed arrays.

Comment: hi mate.. thanks. Do you know that $outputArray is 2D array, correct? it is not a single dimensional array, in which case, your solution would make sense to me.

Comment: I see now remainder of your answer, where you say, that it is legal to have mixed arrays in PHP and JavaScript. +1 for answer. After testing, i will mark this one as the `Accepted Answer`.

Comment: You can even put array in array in array http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/001/122/xzibit-happy.jpg

Comment: worked well, thank you! Although both answers here, yours and Anri's, were correct, I am marking your answer as the `Accepted One` because your answer was the first and provided slightly more detailed explanation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
// prepare output array
$outputArray = array();

// construct 2D array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    // add row to array
    $outputArray[] = $row;
}

// add some variable
$outputArray['myVaraible'] = 'some value';

// close database connection
mysqli_close($dbc);

// construct and output JSON
echo json_encode($outputArray);
```

---

you will see in json array your custom variable